# Get node names based on node values

Tags: xml, powershell

I have following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration APIVersion="1905.1" IPS_CAT_VER="0">
    <Notificationlist transactionid="">
        <SendEmail>Enable</SendEmail>
        <SendSnmp>Disable</SendSnmp>
        <SignInEmail>Enable</SignInEmail>
        <SignInSnmp>Disable</SignInSnmp>
        <TooManyLoginEmail>Disable</TooManyLoginEmail>
        <TooManyLoginSnmp>Disable</TooManyLoginSnmp>
    </Notificationlist>
</Configuration>
```

I need two arrays, one with **Enable** Notificationlist and one with **Disable** Notificationlist like

```
Enable        Disable
------        -------
SendEmail     SendSnmp
SignInEmail   SignInSnmp
              TooManyLoginEmail
              TooManyLoginSnmp
```

I have tried like

```
$xml = (Select-Xml -Path C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\shellscripts\xml\SNMP.xml -XPath '/Configuration/Notificationlist')
$nodes = $xml | ForEach-Object { $_.Node | select -ExpandProperty InnerText }
```

but it only gives node values but not node name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code, which will give you two variables `$Enabled` and `$Disabled`. To give you two arrays for node names for enabled and disabled values:

```
$Enabled = ($xml.Node | GM -MemberType Property | Select Name).Name | %{ if($xml.Node[$_].InnerText -eq "Enable") { $_ } }

$Disabled = ($xml.Node | GM -MemberType Property | Select Name).Name | %{ if($xml.Node[$_].InnerText -eq "Disable") { $_ } }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to do two distinct queries I suggest to load the XML once and then do two XPath queries.

```bash
$xml = [xml]::new(); $xml.Load("C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\shellscripts\xml\SNMP.xml")

$enableNames = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath '/Configuration/Notificationlist/*[text()="Enable"]' | 
               ForEach-Object { $_.Node.Name }

$disableNames = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath '/Configuration/Notificationlist/*[text()="Disable"]' | 
                ForEach-Object { $_.Node.Name }
```

The XPath expression `*[text()="SomeText"]` gives you all elements that have text child nodes with the given text.

To get the node name simply query the `Name` property of the node.